# What is the reason for separating code into modules of an angular2 app?

Tags: angular

I have read the docs, and blogs about how using modules in angular2 helps you to separate code with related functionality into its own unit. I understand the point of modules if you want to build a library as a module that can be imported by other projects. But this seems like a specific use case.

What is the advantage of using modules in a project if I will not use that code in another project? How does organising code into modules in angular2 improve the performance than say having a bunch of components located in your root module?

Haven't been able to find answers to these questions, so any help on answering these would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: A module is a group of files which work together with a specific purpose, a module can be loaded into another project and should not crash. You can chose to load modules asynchronously and therefore improve the performance (example an admin module).

Comment: Can you define in your angular app, when to load a certain module. Or is everything loaded at startup?

Comment: If you have an admin section, that's the most obvious thing that comes to my mind.

Comment: After doing more reading on the subject, I am starting to think that really modules are for building libraries. Thats it. I come from a java background so Ill take an example from there. If I were to write a bunch of code, build it with maven, then import that jar with my pom file in another project. That pom deffinition/import would be the same as importing a module in angular2...Is this correct to say?

Comment: I don't know much about Java, sorry but you are right, libraries use modules. I can only recommend you to [read this doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) even though I think you did it already. The point that interests you the most is probably the lazy loading of modules.